# Table of Contents in PDF viewer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have created one pdf viewer now i want to display Table of Contents just like index and i want to fetch all the pages from that table is there any way or method to do that?

-Thanx any advance

Answer (score 0):

Though this is very old post, Thinking that u might have solved it, I m posting this answer so that others can have solution.

This function is incomplete but can ba a good start. :)

`CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog` function helps you to get table of contents

```
CGPDFDictionaryRef oldDict = CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog(pdf);
CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction(oldDict, copyDictionaryValues, NULL);


void copyDictionaryValues (const char *key, CGPDFObjectRef object, void *info) {
  //  NSLog(@"key: %s", key);
CGPDFObjectType typeObj = CGPDFObjectGetType(object);
switch (typeObj) {
    case kCGPDFObjectTypeDictionary: {
        CGPDFDictionaryRef objectDictionary;
        if (CGPDFObjectGetValue(object, kCGPDFObjectTypeDictionary, &objectDictionary)) {
            CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction(objectDictionary, copyDictionaryValues, NULL);
        }
    }
        break;
    case kCGPDFObjectTypeString: {
        CGPDFStringRef objectString;
        if (CGPDFObjectGetValue(object, kCGPDFObjectTypeString, &objectString)) {
            NSString *tempStr = (NSString *)CGPDFStringCopyTextString(objectString);
            [auxInfo setObject:tempStr
                                    forKey:[NSString stringWithCString:key encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [tempStr release];
        //    NSLog(@"set string value");
        }
    }
        break;
    case kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger: {
        CGPDFInteger objectInteger;
        if (CGPDFObjectGetValue(object, kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger, &objectInteger)) {
            [auxInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:objectInteger]
                                    forKey:[NSString stringWithCString:key encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
       //     NSLog(@"set int value");
        }
    }
        break;
    case kCGPDFObjectTypeBoolean: {
        CGPDFBoolean objectBool;
        if (CGPDFObjectGetValue(object, kCGPDFObjectTypeBoolean, &objectBool)) {
            [auxInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:objectBool]
                                    forKey:[NSString stringWithCString:key encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
       //     NSLog(@"set boolean value");
        }
    }
        break;
    case kCGPDFObjectTypeArray : {
        CGPDFArrayRef objectArray;
        if (CGPDFObjectGetValue(object, kCGPDFObjectTypeArray, &objectArray)) {
        //  copyPDFArray(objectArray);

           NSLog(@"set array value");
        }
    }

}
}
```